# Where does the 'J' in SSJ and SSJ2 come from?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In Dragon Ball Z, the abbreviations for Super Saiyan 1 and 2 are SSJ and SSJ2. However, there is no 'j' in Saiyan, so where does this 'j' come from in the abbreviation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes from the Japanese original name for Super Saiyan: 超{スーパー}サイヤ人{じん}, pronounced *Sūpā Saiya-jin*.

You can read more about it at http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan.

Jin means "people/person." 'Gaikoku-jin' means foreigners.

Comment: Jin mean "People/person" . Gaikoku-jin mean foreigners

Answer (score 2):

It means Super Saiya Jin , jin is "people"
Saiya Jin      = saiya people ,
Namekusei Jin  = namekusei people ,
Nihonjin       = japan     people